# Возведение в степень используя рекуррентное соотношени

Tags: java

Дано действительное положительное число `a` и целое неотрицательное число `n`.

Вычислите `a^n` не используя циклы и функцию `math.pow()`, а используя *рекуррентное соотношение `a^n=a*a^(n-1)`*.

Comment: Покажите ваши наработки и расскажите что в них не так

Comment: Слаб в рекурсии,потому даже не мог представить как это можно было реализовать,потому поинтересовался здесь)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private double pow(double a, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return pow(a, n-1)*a;
}
```

*Но не забывайте про диапазон значений для `double`.*

Comment: Вы вопрос читали? Топикстартер же явно просит не использовать `pow`!

Comment: Вы код смотрели? :)

Comment: @AK, Да, читал. Где здесь Вы видите использование метода `Math.pow(...)`?

Comment: @Barmaley, Какой код?

Comment: @Barmaley спасибо)

Comment: @Barmaley тьфу ты... извините, даже не посмотрел, что тут банальная рекурсия.